# SQL Server 2012 - Inserting multiple records from one block of text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On SQL server 2012. I have normalized tables that will consist of "notes". Each "note" record can have many notelines tied to it with a foreign key. I'm looking for a SQL statement that will parse a block of text and, for each line within that text, insert a separate record.

I'm guessing some sort of "WHILE loop" for each block of text but can't get my head around how it would work.

To be clear: The end result of this would be to just paste the block of text into the query and execute so that I can get each individual line of it into the note without messing around creating multiple insert statements.

Comment: Can you  please show some sample input and expected output

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem vert normailized to me. What's the point of making each line of text a different record, when you can enter the entire note inside a single record?

Comment: I agree that in this instance it's probably not the best way of doing things. This is more of a POC to show that we don't *always* have to use VARCHAR(MAX) to hold freeform text fields (which is prevalent in our organization).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zohar Peled, this is probably not be the right way to normalize these tables. If this is still something you need to do then:

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

Prior to that version; using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

table setup:

```
create table dbo.note (
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key 
    , created datetime2(2) not null
    /* other cols */
);
create table dbo.note_lines (
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
  , noteId int not null foreign key references dbo.note(id)
  , noteLineNumber int not null
  , noteLineText varchar(8000) not null
);
```

insert statements:

```
declare @noteId int; 
insert into dbo.note values (sysutcdatetime());
set @noteId = scope_identity();

declare @note_txt varchar(8000) = 'On SQL server 2012. I have normalized tables that will consist of "notes". Each "note" record can have many notelines tied to it with a foreign key. I''m looking for a SQL statement that will parse a block of text and, for each line within that text, insert a separate record.
I''m guessing some sort of "WHILE loop" for each block of text but can''t get my head around how it would work.
To be clear: The end result of this would be to just paste the block of text into the query and execute so that I can get each individual line of it into the note without messing around creating multiple insert statements.'

insert into dbo.note_lines (noteId, noteLineNumber, noteLineText)
select @noteId, s.ItemNumber, s.Item 
from  [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K](@note_txt, char(10)) s
```

And after the insert:

```
select * from note;
select * from note_lines;
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/SCODAG90159

return (respectively):

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |       created       |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2017-04-06 15:16:59 |
+----+---------------------+

+----+--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | noteId | noteLineNumber |                                                                                                                                    noteLineText                                                                                                                                     |
+----+--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |      1 |              1 | On SQL server 2012. I have normalized tables that will consist of "notes". Each "note" record can have many notelines tied to it with a foreign key. I'm looking for a SQL statement that will parse a block of text and, for each line within that text, insert a separate record. |
|  2 |      1 |              2 | I'm guessing some sort of "WHILE loop" for each block of text but can't get my head around how it would work.                                                                                                                                                                       |
|  3 |      1 |              3 | To be clear: The end result of this would be to just paste the block of text into the query and execute so that I can get each individual line of it into the note without messing around creating multiple insert statements.                                                      |
+----+--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

**Note:** the function used for the example is designed for a limit of 8000 characters, if you need more, then there are alternatives in the links above.

Comment: I love this! I used Jeff Moden's splitter code and it worked great. Since I posted, I had a solution that used charindex but didn't have it quite right. Then I came back here and that function was perfect! Thanks